# Using Typescript with Realm JS

Tags: typescript, react-native, realm

I'm using Realm for react-native.  They say if you want to use schemas on objects, you would do something like:

```
class Person {
  [...]
}
Person.schema = PersonSchema;

// Note here we are passing in the `Person` constructor
let realm = new Realm({schema: [CarSchema, Person]});
```

I want to use Typescript in my projects.  The type definition for `schema` is `ObjectClass[]` where `ObjectClass` is defined as:

```
interface ObjectClass {
    schema: ObjectSchema;
}
interface ObjectSchema {
    name: string;
    primaryKey?: string;
    properties: PropertiesTypes;
}
[ omitted the rest b/c that's not where the type fails ]
```

So, I defined my class:

```
class MyApp implements ObjectClass{
    schema: { name: 'int', properties: { version: 'int' } }
}
```

But, the following fails:

`let realm = new Realm({schema: [MyApp]})`

`Argument of type 'typeof MyApp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectClass'. Property 'schema' is missing in type 'typeof MyApp'.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `schema` property on `MyApp` should be static (and this means you won't be able to implement the interface `ObjectClass`):

```
class MyApp {
    static schema = { name: 'int', properties: { version: 'int' } };
}
```

Comment: Which I think means that I won't really be able to use the typedefs for realm, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: You're not supposed to explicitly implement the `ObjectClass` interface on your class, it will be inferred when you define the static `schema` property on your class. I'm sorry if this doesn't seem intuitive, but TypeScript doesn't allow us to define static members on interfaces.

Comment: This is actually not the correct way to do this, because as it stands now, any objects queries from Realm will have an `Object` prototype, instead of `Realm.Object`. This means that properties like `.entries()`, `.keys()` and `.toJSON()` will not exist, which were causing me some major headaches for a good while.